# This submission failed with error code(s) 1201- Microsoft Store error

Tags: uwp, bundle, desktop-bridge, full-trust

I have developed a UWP app desktop bridge application. Everything seems to work when I build the project. Also, I have uploaded many bundle files to the store which are successfully certified earlier. But, now when I upload a bundle file I get an 1201 with no specific details. What does this error code signifies? How can I fix this issue or are there any means by which I can fix this? please help.. thanks in advance

Comment: This issue has many different possible reasons. Please open a free [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/) to the store team. Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic and select App certification failures for issue type. The team could check which step causes the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I had to create a new bundle file after updating my visual studio. Now it successfully certified the app.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT honestly you can't get anything this way. Last year or so I am just getting the copy paste replies like "we are taking your feedback seriously to improve" for a very precise questions that do have exact answers, sometimes even 'yes' and 'no'. Actually wcak now even ignores my emails. Do you have some other suggestion?